# TestNG testcases fails in eclipse

Tags: testng

I have a weird problem. When I run the TestNG test cases with maven, the test-cases runs fine. However, when I run it using the eclipse testNG plugin, the test-cases are skipped and I find lot of bean creation exception.

In the structure we have a abstract class, which does lot of initialization, could that be the reason ?

Comment: Put some code for someone to help you.  How are you triggering your tests when you say run it using testng plugin - run as suite, class or test?

Comment: I am running as class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the Answer**

I thought I will share it. There multiple problem listed. The TestNG does not compile the code. This is different from JUNIT framework within eclipse. The Junit, complies the code and we can even have data pushed into the actual database and rolled back after testing. The testNG does not provide this facility.

Especially if the project is build using Maven, then the build needs to be triggered outside eclipse. The test needs to be run from eclipse. **This is the key to the solution. This may fail on clean build as the temporary build files will be removed from eclipse. THIS ISSUE IS MAINLY BECAUSE OF THE PROJECT STRUCTURE**

Thanks for all the help.